# Mysql Query for adding and substract

Tags: mysql

```
select
    sum(Account_recharge) as 'Total Recharge',
    sum(Amount_Received) as 'Total Received'
from insert1
cross join received1
    on insert1.id = received1.id
where insert1.Account_Name = 'arvind2';

total recharge    Total received
 1000              500
```

but i want also show `dues =500`

Answer (score 0):

Take the difference between the total recharge and the total received?

```
SELECT
    SUM(Account_recharge) AS `Total Recharge`,
    SUM(Amount_Received) AS `Total Received`,
    SUM(Account_recharge) - SUM(Amount_Received) AS dues
FROM insert1 i1
INNER JOIN received1 r1
    ON i1.id = r1.id
WHERE
    i1.Account_Name = 'arvind2';
```

Note that I replaced the cross join with an inner join.  Cross join doesn't make sense here, because the join has a criteria (though apparently it was working for you in MySQL).

Comment: 'cross' is quietly ignored in MySQL